# Eclipse Deployment assembly for Maven build overlay option

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I have my enterprise project which contains 2 WARs. There are some common resources in those WARs, in project structure we have base project which is web project. and base project contains common resources for 2 WARs. for those 2 WARs in project structure we have 2 separate web project.

When I do build through maven then I use a overlay option of maven to build a 2 WARs to be merged with a base project WAR. So that common resources from base project war is merged in both WARs from EAR.

I have created a eclipse project by following command,

eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 eclipse:configure-workspace

Now I want to configure these project in eclipse(Kepler) so I can run those from eclipse by configuring application server on eclipse.
But above commnad add base war file directly in deployment assembly of WARs from EAR, instead of merging it as happening in overlay option of maven build.

I tried to fix this by manual configuration of deployment assembly but there is no option for adding folders from different project.

I have google a lot for solution for this but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot f google one thought came to my mind, how this is been handled in myeclipse?
I have downloaded myeclipse and imported my project in myeclipse, then added maven nature to all project.

Then I have checked deployment assembly of WAR project, there base project added in deployment assembly without any value in deploy path, then i had opened .setting folder from WAR project I have checked the **org.eclipse.wst.common.component** file where i have found one entry which were doing overlay maven build in deployment assembly, that line is as follows,

```
<dependent-module deploy-path="/" handle="module:/overlay/prj/base-project?includes=**/**&amp;excludes=META-INF/MANIFEST.MF">
            <dependency-type>consumes</dependency-type>
        </dependent-module>
```

here is a solution for overlay issue of maven build, which we need to configure in deployment assembly in component file of .setting folder of project.